# After "lo + adjective + que" constructions does the verb precede/follow the subject?

Tags: gramática, verbos, artículos, orden-de-palabras

I understand that sometimes when the "*lo + adjective + que*" construction is used the verb (in this case, "es") can come before the subject (in this case, "la ley española"). However, I also understand that Spanish is typically an SVO language so is the following sentence correct?

> El resultado del juicio indignó a las feministas en todo España y destaca lo machista que la ley española es.
>
> <sub>The result of the trial infuriated feminists throughout Spain and highlighted how chauvinistic Spanish law is</sub>

Comment: Yes. It is correct. You can say "lo machista que **es** la ley" or "lo machista que la ley ***es**"

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish, word order doesn’t matter as much as in English. Since words are highly inflected, the meaning remains similar even if you move the words around. This is true for your example.

If you rewrote it as “destaca lo machista que es la ley española”, the sentence would still directly translate as “(it) highlights the chauvinistic that is the Spanish law”.

The rewritten version is still very similar in meaning to “how chauvinistic the Spanish law is”, which is the default translation of this grammatical structure.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use de verb after or before the «lo + adjective» structure -it doesn’t make any difference in Spanish- you shouldn’t end your sentence with a verb. so the sentence will be

> «El resultado del juicio indignó a las feministas en toda España y destacó lo machista que es la ley española.»

Notice that ‘toda’ is feminine like ‘España’; and *‘destacó’* is past tense like *‘indignó’*.

Comment: So you are saying that the sentence that ends with the verb is wrong? If so, I disagree.

Comment: I’m saying it. 
Manual de gramática Española Tomo I. Otilia de la Cueva y otros:
«es válido afirmar que en lenguas como el español no se puede considerar un factor determinante el orden de los sintagmas, pues nuestra lengua no exige un orden fijo. ...
Sin embargo, se debe tener cuidado con la colocación del verbo al final de la oración ... Estas construcciones resultan afectadas en nuestra lengua; y salvo en obras poéticas, hay que rechazarlas»

please, give me an example that sounds ok.

Comment: El hecho de que la frase termine en verbo es perfectamente válido en muchos contextos. Si necesitas ejemplos puedes crear una pregunta en el sitio con lo que te parece que no debes ser.